# Strange Jersey exceptions when load testing our web application

Tags: apache, tomcat, jersey, load-testing

we are developing a web application using tomcat servlet container and Jersey as RESTful service engine. The app is deployed on two tomcat nodes, accessed through a single apache webserver in front of them and mod_proxy as load balancer.

With medium load on the system (some thousands of users querying the app), the following errors occur sometimes in the catalina.out logfile, which we do not understand. Processor load is < 20%, memory is pretty much free. It would be great if someone could point us into the right direction where to search for the problem. Thanks a lot! Here comes the error log:

`3131392:27.Apr 17:20:05.827 ERROR  ContainerResponse     - The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
3131393-java.io.IOException
3131394-    at org.apache.jk.common.JkInputStream.receive(JkInputStream.java:205)
3131395-    at org.apache.jk.common.JkInputStream.doRead(JkInputStream.java:179)
3131396-    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:428)
3131397-    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:304)
3131398-    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:405)
3131399-    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:327)
3131400-    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:162)
3131401-    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeTo(ReaderWriter.java:114)
3131402-    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeTo(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:76)
3131403-    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider.readFrom(ByteArrayProvider.java:79)
3131404-    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider.readFrom(ByteArrayProvider.java:59)
3131405-    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:456)
3131406-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
3131407-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
3131408-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:138)
3131409-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
3131410-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:71)
3131411-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:280)
3131412-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
3131413-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
3131414-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
3131415-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
3131416-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1341)
3131417-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1273)
3131418-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1223)
3131419-    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1213)
3131420-    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
3131421-    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
3131422-    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exception. The client starts a request but (maybe the slow connection or disconnection) doesn't complete the request.

You can avoid to receive error log with this exception mapper:

```
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Provider
public class SocketTimeoutExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SocketTimeoutException> {

   public Response toResponse(SocketTimeoutException e) {

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.debug("Read timed out.");

        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

    }

}
```